# Loop through a JSON file with jquery

Tags: jquery, json, loops

I'm trying to loop through some JSON that has some nested data. The JSON structure is such:

```
var data =[
{"otherdata":"tons of other data",
 "studentlist":{
             "user":{
                     "first":"john",
                     "last":"doe",
                     "status":"good", 
                     "id":"100404"
              }, 
            "user":{
                   "first":"jane",
                   "last":"doe",
                   "status":"bad", 
                   "id":"100405"
             }
}];
```

I'm trying to loop through "data", but more importantly, I need to loop through each user. However using jquery's .each(), but it either fails or shows an error for .length. When I'm tracing out in my console.

```
var student = data.studentlist;
$.each(student, function(i, item){
   console.log('student: ' + student.user[i].id);
});
```

Comment: you're not looping through json. json is a text-encoding of a javascript data structure. you're looping through a javascript structure, and it's a JS structure like any other. just because it used to be json is irrelevant. consider JS the wrapping paper your christmas present came in.

Answer (score 1):

You have your data in an array or objects you need to access it like so:

```
data[0].studentlist
```

Or just remove `[]` from around the data then you can access it like this:

```
data.studentlist
```

Also there are other problems with your data structure i.e. you cannot have 2 `"user"` keys you would need to make that an array objects. This is what I believe you want your structure to look like:

```
var data = {
"otherdata":"tons of other data",
    "studentlist":{
         "user":[
                 {
                    "first":"john",
                    "last":"doe",
                    "status":"good", 
                    "id":"100404"
                 }, 
                 {
                    "first":"jane",
                    "last":"doe",
                    "status":"bad", 
                    "id":"100405"
                 }
                ]
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through each user:

```
var length = data[0].studentlist.length;
for(i=0; i<length; i++)
   data[0].studentlist[i];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it:

```
for (var i in data[0].studentlist){
  var user = data[0].studentlist[i];
  console.log('student: ' + user.id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your code, it should work like this:

```
var student = data[0].studentlist;
$.each(student, function(i, item){
  console.log('student: ' + item);
});
```

You might recheck the jquery-each documentation.